# Not Able to mint using Token generated through Solana Playground

Tags: solana-cli, mint

I created one Token using Solana Playground following steps on this [tutorial](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/metadata-pointer#getting-started).
I'm now trying to mint using this token in my terminal using solana-cli.

I'm getting below error.

```
Error: "Account 6aVNcw6PcwC6FjkPH3tUjdMYWCr4YY3SFg6HVt43kYg is owned by 11111111111111111111111111111111, not configured program id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb"
```

I have configured the private key of account 6a.. using command `solana config set -k ./solana-playground-account/id.json`

Can you please point to what could be the issue, and how to mint using this token?

Answer (score 2):

You're using your wallet address in Playground, not the token mint address.

Based on the transactions on the wallet address, I think the mint you want is `2f8ygYd54EAS2eGUrQ2xR3GgoDXd5fvGF7AQzjAZkton`. [This is the transactio](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/66xSMeXBSPPM5TB4j3aWdyC4dSa84KsHTu78yEC3VEfrsEnfVj65p8eh9NMhKE8CzSwH79MVbXKAnXHzTUTeWRy?cluster=devnet)n where you created it - notice your `6aVN...` address is the mint authority, and `2f8y...` is the mint address. [You can see the mint in Explorer too here.](https://explorer.solana.com/address/2f8ygYd54EAS2eGUrQ2xR3GgoDXd5fvGF7AQzjAZkton?cluster=devnet)